# How to use first_or_create to update existing contacts in rails 4 if they exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating an app where users can create embeddable forms that collect contacts for them (email subscribers).

When the user gets a new email subscriber, a new contact is created with the email address, and the contact is associated with the user and the form it was create through.

However right now if the same email gets entered twice, it creates a new contact, instead of updating an existing contact associated with the user.

In my `Contacts` controller, I'm trying to use the `first_or_create` function to check if the user already has a contact with that email address, before creating a new one.

```
def create

      @user = @form.user
      @contact = Contact.where(:user_id => @user, :email => :email).first_or_create(contact_params)
      @contact.user = current_user
      respond_to do |format|
        if @contact.save
          format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'New contact created!' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contacts }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
end
```

While this doesn't return an error when creating a contact, it still creates a duplicate contact.

How do I properly do this?

NOTES: As you can see, I'm also trying to pass `contact_params`, which includes important information like the contacts name, etc.

Here's the models for reference...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forms, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :contacts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base  
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The other advice about protecting your email field is very good and you should do that, but the code you have shouldn't actually be creating a duplicate record if your `where` values are all correct. Add the code to your question showing where `@form.user` is coming from, I suspect that's not what you think it is meaning that `:user_id => @user` isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: ":email => :email" ?

Comment: Is there another way to do that? We're creating the contact, so I can't do @contact.email yet. This is while trying to search the database for existing contacts with the same `:email`

Answer (score 0):

In your contact model, put

```
validates :email, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
```

If you try to create another contact with the same email, validations will fail and a new contact won't be created.

Comment: Would the uniqueness be limited to the users contacts? Or all the contacts in the app? This way if there are two different users getting subscribers with our app's forms, if the same subscriber enters their email in both forms, it doesn't limit them the second time around.

Comment: it depends on how you have your associations setup. maybe posting the has_many or belongs_to would help.

Comment: Thanks. I included the models.

Comment: updated my answer, see if thats what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your contacts table you should pass the unique: true parameter. So it should be ...`t.string :email, unique: true`...instead of just `t.string :email`